# Check GameObject name in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am attempting to make a script in Unity 2D.

Basically, when the player touches a door collider, it would log "Is on door".

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeScene: MonoBehaviour {
  void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Door") {
      Debug.Log("Is On Door");
    }
  }
}
```

But when I touch the collider, nothing happens.

How can I check if the collision game object name is `Door`?

***I don't want to compare with any tag or layer, I want to compare with the name of the GameObject itself.**

Comment: You could rather try `if(collision.gameObject.name.Equals("Door"))` .. besides that .. this **is** how you check for the name .. make sure there are no typos in your names (e.g. you have `"Door"` but your description says you want to check for `"door"`...)  .. Have you tried [**Debugging**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) your code with breakpoints?

Comment: When I tried it, it was normal: if(collision.gameObject.name.Equals("Door"))

Thaks Guy!

Comment: ChangeScene.cs is Component of Player? To receive an OnCollisionEnter event, the object receiving the touch must have a Rigidbody.

Comment: your door have a collider2d o 3d?

Comment: If you add an *else* condition, does that get triggered?

Answer (score 0):

This script should be on the GameObject `Door` to check for other GameObjects it collides with:

```cs
public class ChangeScene: MonoBehaviour {
  void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "door") {
      Debug.Log("Is on Door");
    }
  }
}
```